# How do I bind the result of DataTable.Select() to a ListBox control?

Tags: .net, data-binding, listbox, datatable, datarow

I have the following code:

```
ListBox.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("table_name").Select("some_criteria = match")
ListBox.DisplayMember = "name"
```

The [`DataTable.Select()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(VS.80).aspx) returns an array of [`System.Data.DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(VS.80).aspx) objects.

No matter what I specify in the `ListBox.DisplayMember` property, all I see is the ListBox with the correct number of items all showing as `System.Data.DataRow` instead of the value I want which is in the `"name"` column!

Is it possible to bind to the resulting array from `DataTable.Select()`, instead of looping through it and adding each one to the `ListBox`?

(I've no problem with looping, but doesn't seem an elegant ending!)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy5b8exc(VS.71).aspx) instead.

```
ListBox.DataSource = new DataView(DataSet.Tables("table_name"), "some_criteria = match", "name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
ListBox.DisplayMember = "name"
```

Comment: In most cases you can't bind standard controls directly to a DataTable or a DataRow.  You have to get a DataTableView or a DataRowView.  Josh is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Josh has it right with the DataView. If you need a very large hammer, you can take the array of rows from any DataTable.Select("...") and do a merge into a different DataSet.

```
 DataSet copy = new DataSet();
 copy.Merge(myDataTable.Select("Foo='Bar'"));
 // copy.Tables[0] has a clone
```

That approach for what you're trying to do is most probably overkill but there are instances when you may need to get a datatable out of an array of rows where it's helpful.